# call one function from another function with parameter in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

app.component.ts

```
viewDelete() {
 console.log('s')
 this.isDelete = !this.isDelete
 console.log(this.isDelete);
 this.viewData(id) ==>> I am getting error here id is not defined 
}

viewData(id) {
 console.log('comes')
 this.departmentService.getDepartmentById(id).subscribe(
  res => this.departmentDetail = res,
  error => this.error = error
 )
}
```

I want to call viewData() function from viewDelete() function. It is getting call correctly but argument id in viewData(id) giving error, id is not defined

Comment: the error is right, because where you have defined `id` first of all. Since it's not inside the function so let's assume you have defined at class level, so its very basic question, how to access a class-level variable.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any id parameter inside function. If it is general parameter write `this`

```
viewDelete() {
 console.log('s')
 this.isDelete = !this.isDelete
 console.log(this.isDelete);
 this.viewData(this.id);
}
```

if not and removing one of list element take id from html as parameter

```
viewDelete(id) {
 console.log('s')
 this.isDelete = !this.isDelete
 console.log(this.isDelete);
 this.viewData(id);
}
```

Comment: This is highly dubious. What if it's a list component and there are multiple Id's? Also `this` is not for parameters it's for properties

Comment: Thats why I wrote second example if list it will send as parameter from html

Comment: Fair enough, but when you say "If it is general parameter write this" it doesn't make any sense

Comment: I don't know content of code . I don't know what id is. It may be general id and asking first user if delete or not so attending id to general parameter. If user say yes ,maybe delete it. That's whay i wrote two examples

Comment: for viewDelete() there is no parameter but for viewData(id) there is id parameter from which backend search using this id as parameter so it is required

Comment: So you need to send id from html to first function. If there is no id in function how can you send it to second function

Comment: yes, i can also call viewData and from that function i can call viewDelete it will work perfectly but viewData is used multiple time so i don't want to call viewDelete multiple times but viewDelete is called only one time. So, i want it like that. you are correct but is there any way